# Should I announce my future resignation before I know a precise date?

Tags: resignation, contractors

I'm a contractor for a small company and I work for a big one, should I announce that I'm already applying for other position elsewhere, or should I close my mouth until I'm sure of the date of my resignation?

I already had several interviews and I have plan for others in the day to come.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Never, **ever**, announce that you are leaving a company before you have the new job, and the new start date, secured.

Announcing that you are interviewing elsewhere is a surefire way to be fired before you have your next job in hand.

Wait until you have signed your offer letter at your new company.

However, it is good practice to make sure that once you have secured the new job, that you make sure you can give a full two-weeks notice to your current employer. Generally, your new company will work with you on this, and your current company will appreciate that you at least gave a two-week notice, even if they don't keep you for the full two weeks.

Comment: Or if you have agreed a notice period, stick to it with your current employer. If it is greater than two weeks, it maintains good relationships. As a contractor, relationships with previous employers mean a lot.

Comment: The answer given surely is related to the question, but I'm sure there are cases where the offer letter is both signed and flexible about start date.  And you haven't given any guidance in that scenario (I do realize that the further details exclude that scenario, but you could make the answer useful to everyone who sees the title).

Comment: I feel that my answer fully answered the question. The question had nothing to do with "cases where the offer letter is signed and flexible about start date." The bit I added about two-weeks notice was just a side-note. My answer was clearly useful to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Say nothing until you have a letter of offer, confirming your new position and terms of employment. You don't want to announce your departure, only to have the offer not materialise. You will definitely cause bad feeling, and could end up looking foolish.

Short answer: until you're certain, say nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Never say anything about leaving until all the paperwork for your next job is signed and all dates have been established. Generally speaking when signing up for a new job you can pick a start date and generally speaking you only need to give 2 weeks notice when leaving a job. When I left my last job I picked a date well in the future, and timed telling my company with that date and gave my self a few days off in between. You should avoid saying anything until everything is set in stone as something could always happen.